# How to show 1st FAV only if 3rd fav place odds are between 5 and 6 dollars in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, server

this is for use in Microsoft sql server management studio 2008

Hi i have this data of a running race below:

> Name /fav   / odds /Place
>   John / 3rd  / 5.21 / 1st 
>   Bob  / 1st  / 3.11 / 2nd
>   paul / 6th  /10.10 / 3rd
>   ken  / 4th  / 6.11 / 4th
>   ted  / 7th  /20.44 / 5th 
>   julie/ 8th  /100.00/ 6th
>   rob  / 9th  / 22.11/ 7th
>   rex  /10th  / 33.55/ 8th
>   rod   / 2nd  / 4.11 / 9th
>   nub   / 5th  / 7.34 / 10th

1) I know how to show the 1st fav with no other conditions -> result: (Bob   1st  / 3.11 / 2nd)

2) But How do i  show the 1st FAV(Bob   1st  / 3.11 / 2nd) only if the 3rd fav (John  3rd  / 5.21 / 1st  and 6 dollars) ODDS are between 5 and 6 dollars , which they are for this to work.

Results (Bob   1st  / 3.11 / 2nd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
select * from table1 where fav='1st' 
and exists
(select name from 
table1 
where fav='3rd' and odd between 5 and 6)
```